# React, Apollo and GraphQL architecture/lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to get my head around how the whole lifecycle of a React, Apollo and GraphQL app works. Here is what I believe it is, but would be great if somebody could confirm or correct me please? I've read around and look at a few diagrams of how it pieces together, however some are different or are more of a generic overview.

1. React uses Apollo Client and firstly checks Apollo's localStorage/cache.
2. If nothing is in the cache a POST request is made to `/graphql` with either a query, mutation or subscription you made.
3. On the server, there is GraphQL, Express, and Apollo Server. The resolvers on the server accept the requests and then do their relevant thing (either call a Restful API, or directly interact with a database).
4. The GraphQL server then received back info from the Restful API/database and then sends just 1 request back to the client.
5. Apollo client checks/diffs against localStoage/cache and then passes to React to update the UI.

[image]